# what is 'id' in $row['id'] in the following code

Tags: php

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row["PI_NO"]; ?>
        <!-- HERE IS THE START OF YOUR TWO HIDDEN INPUT -->
        <input type="hidden" name="piaddress[]" value="<?php echo $row["PI_ADDRESS"]; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer[]" value="<?php echo $row["CUSTOMER_NAME"]; ?>">
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $row['CUSTOMER_NAME']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['PI_ADDRESS']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
?>

<input type="submit" value="save" id="submit">
</form>
```

In this code of form submission i am not able to understand that what is 'id' in $row['id'] .... 
if it is the same id as in `<input name="value" type="checkbox" id="hi">`
then how is it not an error when echoed `$row['id']`

this code is used to be insert the rows checked into another table

in case of more clarity please reply

Comment: Where is this code from? `$row['id']` is the column `id` in `$row`, which is probably from some kind of table (MySQL?). `id` is just another column, like `CUSTOMER_NAME` and `PI_ADDRESS`.

Comment: there is no mention of 'id' anywhere else in the code :(

Comment: well for sure id is not another column ... i checked it :(

Comment: The column (field) called `id` exists in the table. If it doesn't you'll have to find some other identifier to use (or add the column).

Answer (score 2):

The id in `$row['id']` is the field picked from your database table,

The id in `<input name="value" type="checkbox" id="hi">` is the identifier of that particualr element

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

That tells you what `$row` is, it is one row from a result set obtained after running a mysql query (not shown in your code), `id` is just one of the fields in that row.

And no, it is not the checkbox that you mentioned.  HTML `id` values are not sent with form submissions. `name`/ `value` pairs are submitted.